# Convert mixed list to string

Tags: python, string, list

I have the list below, which contains strings and integers. How do I make a string of them? Tried to use

```
''.join(l)
```

but it does't work, because there are integers on the list(specifically, `L[1]` is an integer, and the others are all strings.). Can you help?

```
L=['1', 9, ':', '0', '5', ':', '4', '5']
#expected "19:05:45"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert each number in the list into a string with a for loop or list comprehension. Like so:

```
l = ['1', 9, ':', '0', '5', ':', '4', '5']

''.join([str(x) for x in l])

'19:05:45'
```

Comment: You can omit the square brackets in the second line. That looks cleaner.

Comment: @Wombatz be careful! Removing the square brackets would make that statement a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, the change isn't purely syntactic/visual.

Comment: @Alexander it surely isn't but the end result is the same plus it is more readable.

Comment: I don't, much to the contrary. I just commented on someone else's answer about how generator expressions might be _slower_ than list comprehensions when it comes to `join`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/11301900.

Comment: My comment was just to warn you that omitting the square brackets changes the meaning of the program, not just the look of it.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile join  try to keep everything in memory then perform operation, that make it slow

Comment: @prashantrana You mean that’s what makes list comprehensions slower in `join`, right?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes

Answer (score 4):

Generators are perfect in this case:

```
>>> l = ['1', 9, ':', '0', '5', ':', '4', '5']
>>> ''.join(str(x) for x in l)
'19:05:45'
```

This looks the same as a list comprehension but does not require the creation of another list instance.

Comment: It seems that in the case of `join`, a list comprehension may be better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/11301900. It certainly did not think that would be the case.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile You are correct there is a small performance improvement, however, in this case, the difference (on my machine) is +-0.2us. The list vs genex is quite complex for small sequences lists are often faster, most of my projects would quickly exhaust your machines ram without generators.

Comment: Oh yes, 99% of the time if you can use a generator expression then you should!

Answer (score 3):

Just map all the elements to string before joining.

```
>>> ''.join(map(str,['1', 9, ':', '0', '5', ':', '4', '5']))
'19:05:45'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a for loop

```
list_str = ''
for i in l:
    list_str += str(i)
```

Or a with a list comprehension

```
list_str = ''.join([str(i) for i in l])
```